# is there any elegant way to return None rather that object based on string

Tags: scala

Is there any elegant way to return None rather than an object if the string inputted is empty?

bellow is a crude example of what I want to achieve

```
private def foo(input: String): Option[Object] = {
   Some(Object(input)) //return None instead if input is empty
}
```

*PS : What I mean by elegant is for me to not create/define another function to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala 2.13.x offers the `Option.when()` method.

```
def foo(input: String): Option[Object] =
  Option.when(input.nonEmpty)(Object(input))
```

Comment: What should I do with all my `Option(input).filterNot(_.isEmpty)`? Is it recyclable or just put it out with the trash?

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(input: String): Option[Object] =
  if(input.nonEmpty)
    Some(Object(input))
  else
    None
```

It will be instantly parsed by anyone reading your code, so really, it doesn't get better than that.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, following @jwvh answer, `Option.unless` uses the negated predicate as declared in `Option.when`,

```
private def foo(input: String): Option[Object] = {
   Option.unless(input.isEmpty)(Object(input))
}
```